# converting from int to enum

Tags: c++

I have declared the following enum :

```
  enum periods {one, five, ten, fifteen, thirty};
```

and now I want to pass it as a commandline argument in my main function.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  periods mp;
  if (argc == 2) {
      std::string min_prd(argv[2]);
      mp=atoi(min_prd.c_str());
 }
```

and the compiler complains:

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘periods’
```

I did atoi() because I figured enum is an int - how do I fix my code?

Comment: Note that this looks like confusion waiting to happen.  `one`==0, `five`==1, `ten`==2, etc.  So `static_cast<periods>(atoi("1"))`==`five`, and `static_cast<periods>(atoi("15"))` is likely nasal demons.

Comment: Also, if `argc`==2, then `argv[2]`==`NULL`.  `argc`==2 means there are two elements in the `argv` array, namely `argv[0]` and `argv[1]`.  Standard behavior is that `argv[2]` be set to `NULL`, as redundant evidence that the end of the argument vector has been reached.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to explicitly cast it:

```
mp=static_cast<periods>(atoi(min_prd.c_str()));
```

Answer (score 3):

I have declared the following enum :

```
enum periods {one, five, ten, fifteen, thirty};
```

and now I want to pass it as a commandline argument in my main function.

```
periods mp = atoi(argv[2]);   // simplified for answer...
```

So, there are several issues:

- you need to cast the int returned by `atoi` to the enum type... `static_cast<periods>(...)`
- you should realise that an argv[2] of "0" will be mapped to the enumeration identifier "one", "1" will map to "five" etc...

  - if you actually want "1" to map to "one", "5" to "five" etc., the easiest way is to change your enum: `enum periods { one = 1, five = 5, ten = 10, fifteen = 15, thirty = 30 };`, but your example's obviously a little contrived so it's impossible to guess what will work best for your real needs
- there's no validation

You're better off creating a function:

```
periods to_periods(const std::string& s)
{
    if (s == "one") return one;
    if (s == "five") return five;
    if (s == "ten") return ten;
    if (s == "fifteen") return fifteen;
    if (s == "thirty") return thirty;
    throw std::runtime_error("invalid conversion from text to periods");
}
```

(When there are more cases, it's not uncommon to use a `std::map` or sorted `std::vector` to track these associations, and it allows reusable algorithms and the same data to support conversions from enum numeric value to textual identifier.)

Comment: Those are `const char*`.  Using `==` for comparisons compares pointers, not string values.  This function will ALWAYS throw the exception.

Comment: Simple fix: change the argument to `std::string const&`.

Comment: Ahhh... what a day :-(.  Thanks Managu.

Answer (score 3):

The straightforward solution is to use `static_cast` (as the other answer has already posted it):

```
periods mp;
if (argc == 2)
{
   std::string min_prd(argv[1]); //the index should be 1
   mp = static_cast<periods>(atoi(min_prd.c_str()));
}
```

But then `atoi` should **not** be used to convert the  c-string into int, because `atoi` doesn't check for error in the input string, hence it is **unsafe**.

C++11 provides safer conversion functions, so you could use [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) as:

```
try
{
   periods mp;
   if (argc == 2)
   {
      //std::stoi could throw exception on error in input
      mp = static_cast<periods>(std::stoi(argv[1]));
   }
   //use mp here
}
catch(std::exception const & e)
{
   std::cout << "exception caught with message : " << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```

Now that is a better solution.

---

However, there is an alternative solution which you could use as:

```
period mp;
if (argc == 2)
{
   mp = to_period(argv[1]); //how should we implement it?
   if (mp == period_end)
   {
       std::cout << "command line input error" << std::endl;
       return 0;
   }
}
```

Now the question is, how should we implement `to_period` function?

**Note that this solution assumes that the command line argument for enum value `one` would be its string representation, i.e it would be `"one"` instead of `1` which is integral representation.**

I would implement this solution as:

- First create a header file called `period_items.h` as:

  ```
  //period_items.h
  E(one)
  E(five)
  E(ten)
  E(fifteen)
  E(thirty)
  ```
- then create another header file called `period.h` as:

  ```
  //period.h
  #include <string>

  enum period 
  {
     #define E(item)  item,
       #include "period_items.h"
     #undef E
     period_end
  };

  period to_period(std::string const & name)
  {
     #define E(item)  if(name == #item) return item;
       #include "period_items.h"
     #undef E
     return period_end;
  }
  ```

Now you can simply include `period.h` and use `to_period` function. :-)

Note that in the alternative solution, I've used singular form rather than plural form, means I've used `period` rather than `periods`. I feel `period` is appropriate.

You could also add this function to `period.h` as:

```
std::string to_string(period value)
{
    #define E(item)  if(value == item) return #item;
        #include "period_items.h"
    #undef E
    return "<error>";
}
```

Now, you could write this:

```
#include "period.h"

period v = to_period(argv[1)); //string to period
std::string s = to_string(v);  //period to string
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

At a random guess, what you really want is something more like:

```
periods mp;
if (argc < 2) {
    mp=one; // default value
} else if (strcmp(argv[1], "one")==0) {
    mp=one;
} else if (strcmp(argv[1], "five")==0) {
    mp=five;
} else if (strcmp(argv[1], "ten")==0) {
    mp=ten;
} else if (strcmp(argv[1], "fifteen")==0) {
    mp=fifteen;
} else if (strcmp(argv[1], "thirty")==0) {
    mp=thirty;
} else {
    fprintf(stderr, "I can't possibly comprehend periods = '%s'\n", argv[1]);
    return -1;
}
```